# What is name of clutch system in a roller shade?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, power-transmission

I am trying to figure out what the exact term is for the clutch system used in a roll-up window shade.

I thought they were called centrifical clutches, but that typically gives me the opposite results like what is used in an automatic vehicle. Where speed causes it to engage.

Basically I want to look up some existing designs because I'm trying to create a product that uses one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a spring-loaded ratchet and pawl system. the pawl mechanism is unlocked by the centripetal force of the initial rolling of the shade by a user.

Here is a diagram. [image: diagram.]

Answer (score 1):

A roller or inclined ramp clutch may be what you are talking about.

Comment: also can be known as a sprag clutch